# SAS-Create Unique Encounters based on Minimal Difference in Dates

Tags: sorting, date, sas, proc-sql

I am trying to sort data from two tables that pairs the closes date from table 1 with the closest date from table 2 (if exists).  There may be ID-dates from table 1 that do not have a match in table 2 and vice versa.  Is not guaranteed to be a 1:1 match either.  For for instance my data from t1 would be something like:

```
ID  time1
A   01/09/2015
A   02/16/2015
B   03/03/2015
C   04/01/2015
C   01/20/2015
C   03/15/2015
```

t2 similarly:

```
ID  time2
A   01/29/2015
A   02/19/2015
B   03/06/2015
C   01/27/2015
C   03/18/2015
C   04/04/2015
```

What I don't want when joining on ID is a combination of all unique dates, rather combinations where the days between are minimum eg.

desired_output:

```
ID  date_time1   date_time2
A   01/09/2015   01/29/2015
A   02/16/2015   02/19/2015
B   03/03/2015   03/06/2015
C   01/20/2015   01/27/2015
C   03/15/2015   03/18/2015
C   04/01/2015   04/04/2015
```

I am not sure how to do this, I have tried selecting the max and min but that only gives something like, which is not what I want:

```
ID  date_time1  date_time2
A   01/09/2015   02/19/2015
B   03/03/2015   03/06/2015
C   01/20/2015   04/04/2015
```

Any ideas/suggestions for how to do this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I used two built-in SAS datasets as examples, but the general idea here is that you want to compare each date within an group in `t1` with each date within the same id group in `t2`, determine the minimum date difference, and keep only that one.

```
data t1 (keep = id date rename = date = time1);
    set sasuser.admitjune;
    if mod(_n_, 2) = 0 then id = "A";
        else id = "B";
run;

data t2 (keep = id date rename = date = time2);
    set sasuser.admitjune;
    if mod(_n_, 2) = 0 then id = "B";
        else id = "A";
    date = date + 3; /*adjusting the dates so the datasets aren't the same*/
run;
```

To do this, you sort by ascending difference in dates and nodup to keep only the closest one:

```
proc sql;
    create table desired_output as select
        a.id, a.time1, b.time2 as nearest_time2,
        abs(b.time2-a.time1) as diff
        from t1 as a
        left join t2 as b
        on a.id = b.id and b.time2 > a.time1
        group by a.id, a.time1
        order by calculated diff;
    proc sort nodupkey; by id time1;
quit;
```

Comment: You might want to a `and b.time2 > a.time1` to your join condition to ensure the `time2` event is after the `time1` event.

Comment: I changed the description up a little because I think it was unclear what I was trying to. I am trying to sort data from two tables that pairs the closes date from table 1 with the closest date from table 2 (if exists).  But that is a good addition Chris J.

Comment: So by closest, you want closest *following* date (i.e., date2 MUST be later than date1)?

Comment: that is correct.  And there may be multiple date ranges per ID, so I am trying to the pair the closest start and end dates for each ID, to create an encounter

Comment: Also I have updated sample data to hopefully show more clearly what I am trying to do.

Comment: The solution provided should solve your problem. What goes wrong when you run it?